Laravel Observer depedency injection gave a collection instance
Laravel Observer depedency injection gave a string type attribute instead of an integer.
I faced a problem with Laravel Observer because it gave me a collection with the wrong attribute type (integers become strings). I fixed this by calling the refresh() method. This is my code:
Observer:
class PaymentObserver implements ShouldHandleEventsAfterCommit
{
    /**
     * Handle the Payment "created" event.
     */
    public function created(Payment $payment): void
    {
        $payment->refresh(); // need refresh or refactch data
        $barbershop                 = Barbershop::find($payment->barbershop_id);
        $barbershop->status         = BarbershopStatusEnum::ACTIVE;
        $barbershop->expired_date   = Carbon::now()->addDays($payment->days_added);
        $barbershop->save();
    }
}

Filament Action: create new Payment
->action(function(Barbershop $barbershop, array $data){
  try{
    $data['user_id'] = Auth::user()->id;
    $barbershop->payments()->create($data);
    Notification::make()->title('Saved successfully')->success()->send();
  }catch(Exception $e){
    Notification::make()->title('Save Failed! ' . $e->getMessage())->danger()->send();
  }
})

Focus on amount and days_added property.
$payment before refresh():
image here
$payment after refresh()
image here
I am already trying to use attribute casting before fixing it with refresh(), and nothing happens. Perhaps this is a bug or just my mistake, let's discuss.
Note:

I use Laravel 11
I use filament


Please include code in your question rather than an image.  Ensure images appear in post if you are using them.  It makes it easier to debug and help.
